# How can I display values in the order of users' answers

Tags: javascript, html

I've been running this code and so far I see no errors but the display function just would work... The desired output will be something like NameAgeValue on the very top of the screen. Any solutions or errors that I'm not aware of?

```
<html>
    <header>
        <style>
            body{
                font-size:16px;
            }
            #maintext{
                font-size:40px;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
           
            function submitsurvey(){
               window.name = document.getElementById("name").value;
               window.age = document.getElementById("age").value;
               window.gender = document.getElementById("gender").value;
          
            function getgender(){
                if (document.getElementById("gender1").checked == true){
                    window.male= document.getElementById("gender1").value;
                }
                if (document.getElementById("gender2").checked == true){
                    window.male= document.getElementById("gender2").value;
                }
                if (document.getElementById("gender3").checked == true){
                    window.male= document.getElementById("gender3").value;
                }
                if (document.getElementById("gender4").checked == true){
                    window.male= document.getElementById("gender4").value;
                }
                
            }
            function display(){
                document.getElementById("maintext").innerHTML = window.age + window.name + window.male; //strings will concatinate
            }
        </script>
    </header>
    <body>
        <div id="maintext"></div>
        Name: <input type="text" id="name" value=""><br><br>
        Age: <input type ="text" id="age" value=""><br><br>
        <form id="gender">
        Gender: <br><input type="radio" value="Male" id="gender1" name= "gender">Male
        <br><input type="radio" value="Female" id="gender2" name= "gender">Female
        <br><input type="radio" value="Other" id="gender3" name= "gender">Other
        <br><input type="radio" value="NoInfo" id="gender4" name= "gender">I prefer not to disclose
        </form>
        <br><br> 
        Please leave any other comments below!<br>
        <textarea id="comments" cols="'30" rows="5"></textarea><br><br> 
        <button onclick=submitsurvey()>Submit Survey</button>  
        <button onlcick=display()>Display Name (run after submit)</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please remember that [JavaScript is not Java](http://javascriptisnotjava.com/) when tagging your questions.

Comment: im sorry I am a beginner so I am not familiar w the tags but I will be careful next time

Answer (score 1):

I do not suggest you keep using `<br />`. I helped you to rewrite with CSS.

Notice it:

- submitsurvey function missing `}`
- It should spell onclick on your button and use quotation mark to wrap it
- textarea cols --> `"30"`

Useful links:

- Radio input - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/radio
- ForEach - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 25px;
        max-width: 500px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      .section1 {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 10px;
      }
      p {
        margin: 0;
      }
      #maintext {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 15px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="maintext"></div>
      <div class="section1">
        <div>Name: <input type="text" id="name" value="" /></div>
        <div>
          Age:
          <input type="text" id="age" value="" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <form>
        Gender:
        <div>
          <input type="radio" value="Male" id="Male" name="gender" />
          <label for="Male">Male</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="radio" value="Female" id="Female" name="gender" />
          <label for="Female">Female</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="radio" value="Other" id="Other" name="gender" />
          <label for="Other">Other</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="radio" value="NoInfo" id="NoInfo" name="gender" />
          <label for="NoInfo">I prefer not to disclose</label>
        </div>
      </form>
      Please leave any other comments below!
      <textarea id="comments" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
      <button onclick="submitsurvey()">Submit Survey</button>
      <button onclick="display()">Display Name (run after submit)</button>
    </div>
    <script>
      var name, age, gender;

      document.querySelectorAll('input[name=gender]').forEach((el) => {
        el.addEventListener('click', () => {
          gender = el.value;
        });
      });

      function submitsurvey() {
        name = document.getElementById('name').value;
        age = document.getElementById('age').value;

        console.log({ name: name, age: age, gender: gender });
      }

      function display() {
        document.getElementById('maintext').innerHTML = `
          <h2>Result:</h2>
          <p>Your name: ${name}</p>
          <p>Your age: ${age}</p>
          <p>Your gender: ${gender}</p>
        `;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add your code to your answer rather than posting it on an external site. Many thanks.

Comment: thank you so much, it was the onclick typo that was making my code malfunctioning. and I appreciate the upgraded ver of my original code haha thanks